# How to search in C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string search query which I have from the frontend app but I have a problem with the query.

I have a list of objects which have Id (number = int).

If the user will write in the search box number 12(string) he should have all lists of objects which contains the number 12 in id.

Objects (1,8,80,90,180);
Another example is if the user will input the number 8. He should have output 8,80,180;

How to write linq for questions about such a thing?

Any example remember search query is a string and id is a number :(

Comment: *searchQuery is string* -- What do you mean? Please clarify and show what you have so far. Currently we have nothing to go by.

Comment: public IActionResult GetCategory(int categoryId, string searchQuery) 
{
int.TryParse(searchQuery, out int numberId)
   queryGuestion = queryQuestion.where(x => x.Name.Contains() || x.numberId.Equals(numberId) || x.numberId.ToString().contains(searchQuery)

)
}

and is not working propery I have problem with number with two digits. If I will input numberId 11,12 I don;t see this objects

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add this info.

Comment: thx for help  I started changing the order of the commands linq and start working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this

```
var input = "8";
var integers = new[] { 8, 80, 810, 70 };
var result = integers.Where(x => x.ToString().Contains(input));
```

Comment: So I input 8 and no respond :(  I added after x  numberId and still is not wroking

integers.Where(x => x.numberId.ToString().Contains(input)); :(

Comment: @KrzysztofBojarczuk If it's an integer then you should first convert it to int, you can use int.Parse or int.TryParse

`int searchQueryIntVal = int.Parse(searchQuery);
var filteredObjects = integers.Where(o => o.Id.ToString().Contains(searchQueryIntVal)).ToList();`

Comment: @KrzysztofBojarczuk, I am not sure why it is not working for you, but here is a dotnetfiddle for you to try it out your self: https://dotnetfiddle.net/h6SLVY

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public class MyObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var arr = new MyObject[]
        {
            new MyObject() { Id = 1 },
            new MyObject() { Id = 8 },
            new MyObject() { Id = 80 },
            new MyObject() { Id = 90 },
            new MyObject() { Id = 180 }
        };

        var searchQuery = "8";
        
        var result = arr.Where(x => x.Id.ToString()
            .Contains(searchQuery))
            .Select(x => x.Id)
            .ToList();
        
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", result));
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/AiIdg2

Comment: The only answer so far that follows the question attentively

Comment: public IActionResult GetCategory(int categoryId, string searchQuery) { int.TryParse(searchQuery, out int numberId) queryGuestion = queryQuestion.where(x => x.Name.Contains() || x.numberId.Equals(numberId) || x.numberId.ToString().contains(searchQuery) ) } and is not working propery I have problem with number with two digits. If I will input numberId 11,12 I don;t see this objects

Comment: Well of course it won't work, the list doesn't contain 11 or 12.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could be enough:

```
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
  internal class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var items = new[]
      {
        new Item { Id = 8 },
        new Item { Id = 18 },
        new Item { Id = 80 },
        new Item { Id = 6 },
        new Item { Id = 13 },
      };

      var itemsWithSearchString = items
        .Select(x => new { Item = x, SearchString = x.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) })
        .ToArray();

      const string userInput = "8";

      var matchingItems = itemsWithSearchString
        .Where(x => x.SearchString.Contains(userInput, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        .Select(x => x.Item)
        .ToArray();

      foreach (var item in matchingItems)
      {
        Console.WriteLine($"Matching item: {item}");
      }
    }
  }

  public class Item
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
      return $"Id {this.Id}";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: public IActionResult GetCategory(int categoryId, string searchQuery) { int.TryParse(searchQuery, out int numberId) queryGuestion = queryQuestion.where(x => x.Name.Contains() || x.numberId.Equals(numberId) || x.numberId.ToString().contains(searchQuery) ) } and is not working propery I have problem with number with two digits. If I will input numberId 11,12 I don;t see this objects